# Cache translation files in an angular app 6

Tags: angular, nginx, browser-cache, ngx-translate

I'm trying to cache my translation files in my angular app as they become more and more heavy to load per each module, I want to cache those files in the browser cache storage, and then be able to use them every time the app needs them.

I'm currently using TranslateHttpLoader with ngx-translate to load my files using :

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/home/', '.json');
}
```

My app.module :

```
.
.
.
TranslateModule.forChild({
              loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            },
            isolate: true
 }),
.
.
.
```

Any idea how to achieve that, much appreciated.

Comment: so browser does not cache those files?

Comment: apparently, yes, I can't find them no where in cache storage in the browser, I'v checked my browser,  both om my 'cache storage' and 'local storage' are empty

Comment: I mean by examining network traffic, does browser send actual request to server or not?

Comment: yes, the browser is sending request every time.

Comment: Why can't you save the json response in service and call only if it is not there?

Comment: you mean like putting my 'createTranslateLoader' in a  service ?

Comment: Cus I'm not doing much in my component, I'm just 
calling 
this.translate.setDefaultLang(language_id) and then my 'ngx-translate' do the rest

Comment: Check your server caching params. I'm using the same lib and my files are cached. Though, now I use @angular/pwa to better handle all caches (assets)

Comment: I had thought of that, Iv' added in my nginx config file, the location to cache the .json file : 
location ~* .(json)$ {
            expires 1d;
        }

Comment: Perhaps I need to add some config, do you have a config exemple to enable caching properly ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is from this link:
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/1005.
Quick fix that will make ngx-translate load new json file every time you refresh page. Not efficient at all but simple and works;)
app.module.ts:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json?v=' + Date.now());
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
...
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
```